# Can I put an iPa file on Android?

Tags: android, installation, ipa

Hi tech buddies how's your SKActions coming along, maybe this has already been answered, I don't know, I just didn't have 8 hours to spend looking through the searches,:).  Basically, can I put an iPa file on Android.  How and will it work, as in can I install it and play it on the android phone.  If not, how do I do it? Thanks, may the Swift be with you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are talking about an apple installer? You can store it on an android device as a file, but Android devices use the APK format as the install file format. The IPA file will not be able to be installed on an Android device.